# Keyboard layout in remote desktop

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

I need to be able to remotely change the keyboard layout of a machine. Will changing the keyboard layout in remote desktop change it for the physical machine? I have not been able to find any answers online. It is a Windows 7 PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the keyboard settings is a user specific setting.

This means, that whenever you change this, it changes for the currently logged in user only. If you login using remote desktop, or locally does not matter.

Alternatively, a group policy could alter these settings too, but the group policy simply changes the setting during login.

Answer (score 1):

If you are navigating the settings of the client machine remotely, yes the changes will stick.

If you, while connected to the client machine, change the settings on the host machine, nothing will change on the client machine except the input received from the host machine.

Comment: This could be a great answer, but the wording you used made me lose it. I've provided my own answer due to this reason. If your wording were better I would have upvoted your answer instead.